# How to automatically connect to Cerberus Network

Tags: mass-effect-2, me2-cerberus-network

My ME2 game is not tied to Origin even though I purchased the retail version. I got a Cerberus Network pass through which I connect to the Cerberus Network.

Upon starting my game the game attempts to connect to the Cerberus Network:
[image: Connecting to Cerberus]

It always leads to failure:
[image]

Then I click OK, takes me back to previous screen where there is a Connect button. I click that and I get this screen:
[image]

How can I have it log me in automagically? I do not want to keep providing credentials each time.

Comment: btw. I've tried solutions provided there and they didn't work

Comment: This will likely end up closed as a duplicate. If you're hoping to draw some attention to it for an answer, you could try putting a bounty on the other question. I suspect this problem isn't solvable though... I think something changed on their server end and they just never bothered updating the game.